# What is the definition of $2.5!$? (2.5 factorial)

Tags: factorial, calculator

I was messing around with my TI-84 Plus Silver Edition calculator and discovered that it will actually give me values when taking the factorial of any number $n/2$ where $n$ is any integer greater than $-2$. Why does this happen? I thought factorials were only defined for positive integers and $0$, so what is my calculator doing to get the answer $3.32335097$ when I enter $2.5!$? Is there actually a definition of $2.5!$ or is my calculator just being weird? How is the factorial function implemented?

I understand the binary implications of $2.5$, so that could possibly have something to do with it. I get a domain error when trying to take the factorial of $-1, 2.3, e$, and any number that is not of the form $n/2$ where $n$ is any integer greater than $-2$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is an extension of the factorial to "most" numbers (including complex numbers) called the [Gamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), $\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{z-1}dt$.  It satisfies $\Gamma(n+1) = n!$, and more generally, that $\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z)$ for any number $z$.

It is a curious fact that $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\pi}$.  Using this, together with the fact that $\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z)$, we get

\begin{align*}2.5! &= \Gamma(3.5) \\\ &= 2.5\cdot\Gamma(2.5) \\\ &= 2.5\cdot 1.5\cdot \Gamma(1.5) \\\ &= 2.5\cdot 1.5\cdot .5\cdot \Gamma(.5)\\\  &= 2.5\cdot 1.5\cdot .5\cdot \sqrt{\pi} \\\ &= 3.32335097...  \end{align*}

Answer (score 8):

The other answers have already given nice explanations, so I shall instead be teaching a different lesson: as always, when confronted with seemingly peculiar behavior in your device, taking a look at your fine device's fine manual is almost always a profitable first step. As it turns out, looking at page 58 of [your fine calculator's fine manual](http://education.ti.com/downloads/guidebooks/graphing/84p/TI84Plus_guidebook_EN.pdf) mentions the following:

[image: calculator manual excerpt]

So yes, do read the fine manual. ;)

---

As a further addition: there is what is called [Gauss's duplication formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E5), which in factorial form goes as

$$\left(n+\frac12\right)!=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}(2n+2)!}{4^{n+1}(n+1)!}$$

This allows you to express factorials of semi-integers in terms of factorials and $\left(-\frac12\right)!=\sqrt \pi$.

Answer (score 4):

The factorial of a positive real number $s$ is defined as 
$$
   s! = \int_0^\infty x^s \exp(-x) \mathrm{d} x
$$
It is easy to verify, integrating by parts, that the definition satisfies the recurrence equation of the factorial:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
 s! &=& \int_0^\infty x^s \exp(-x) \mathrm{d} x = \int_0^\infty x^s \mathrm{d} (-\exp(-x) ) \\ &=& 
   \left.\left(- x^s \exp(-x) \right) \right|_{x \downarrow 0}^{x \uparrow \infty} + s \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \exp(-x) \mathrm{d} x =
  s (s-1)!
\end{eqnarray}
$$
The limit $\lim_{x \to +\infty}  x^s \exp(-x) = \lim_{x \to +\infty}  \frac{x^s}{\exp(x)} = 0$, since exponential function grows faster than any polynomial, and $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} x^s \exp(-x) \leqslant  \lim_{x \downarrow 0} x^s = 0$, since $s$ was assumed positive.

The above, of course, is the celebrated [Euler integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). It is worth noting, that Euler integral is not the only possible extension of factorial to positive real axis, but the only one which is logarithmically convex, see [Bohr–Mollerup theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem).